# Python regex example

Tags: python

If I want to replace a pattern in the following statement structure:

```
cat&345;
bat &#hut;
```

I want to replace elements starting from `&` and ending before (not including `;`). What is the best way to do so?

Comment: are both of those one string

Comment: No, 2 separate strings

Comment: Good question, but please show also what you have been trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including or not including the & in the replacement?

```
>>> re.sub(r'&.*?(?=;)','REPL','cat&345;')           # including
'catREPL;'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=&).*?(?=;)','REPL','bat &#hut;')    # not including
'bat &REPL;'
```

#### Explanation:

- Although not required here, use a `r'raw string'` to prevent having to escape backslashes which often occur in regular expressions.
- `.*?` is a "non-greedy" match of anything, which makes the match stop at the first semicolon.
- `(?=;)` the match must be followed by a semicolon, but it is not included in the match.
- `(?<=&)` the match must be preceded by an ampersand, but it is not included in the match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good regex
`import re

result = re.sub("(?<=\\&).*(?=;)", replacementstr, searchText)`
Basically this will put the replacement in between the `&` and the `;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go a different direction all together and [use `HTMLParser.unescape()`](http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/).  The `unescape()` method is undocumented, but it doesn't appear to be "internal" because it doesn't have a leading underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated character classes to do this:

```
import re

st='''\
cat&345;
bat &#hut;'''

for line in st.splitlines():
    print line
    print re.sub(r'([^&]*)&[^;]*;',r'\1;',line)
```